# Jwplayer fails to play video in html5 mode, but works fine in flash mode

Tags: jquery, html, jwplayer

I am loading an xml file in jwplayer to play videos depending on which link is clicked. Below is my jwplayer setup code, and xml:

Jwplayer:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 jwplayer("player-container").setup({
 autostart: true,
 'modes': [
   {type: 'html5'}, 
   {type: 'flash', src: '/assets/components/mediaplayer-5.8/5.9/player.swf',config:{
        skin: "/assets/components/mediaplayer-5.8/modieus.swf"        
     }},
    {type: 'download'}
    ],    
 repeat: 'list',
 width: 480
    });
  jwplayer().load('/media/narration.xml')
</script>
```

Sample XML:

```
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/">
  <channel>
    <title>Sample File</title>

 <item>
      <title>peking</title>
      <link></link>
      <description></description>

      <pubDate>Sat, 07 Sep 2002 09:42:31 GMT</pubDate>

      <media:content url="/videos/Peking Edit For Web-7.mp4" />
      <media:thumbnail url="/images/playerimg.jpg" />

</item>

  </channel>
</rss>
```

However, no video is playing. But if I bring `{type: 'html5'}` below `flash`, videos show up correctly. Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Does putting the `<media:content>` and `<media:thumbnail>` inside a `<media:group>` make any difference?  I noticed they use that for the playlist files on their [xml playlist testing page](http://developer.longtailvideo.com/player/trunk/fl5/js/test/examples/xmlplaylists.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that just because a file is mp4, it might not always play in jwplayer. I had to encode it with H264 to get them to play properly. I used a software called "[handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/)" for this.

Answer (score 0):

JW PLayer tries to play the video according to the types specified in the mode parameter, in the order that they are specified. So if HTML5 is before Flash, it will try to play in HTML5 first. HTML5 uses the  tag so try to wrap the  statement inside a video tag